# mi carrusel bootstrap dinamico no me funciona

Tags: bootstrap, imagen, bootstrap-carousel

estoy teniendo un problemilla, trato de mostrar en un carrusel de bootstrap las imagenes de un directorio, pero no funciona porque todas las pone como item active, y no encuentro el error en mi codigo. Alguien que me ayude....

```
<div id="imagenes" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
     <?php  $path = 'images/art/'.$id;
     if (file_exists($path)){
         $directorio = opendir($path);
         $i=1;
         while (false !== ($archivo = readdir($directorio))){
             if (!is_dir($archivo)){
                 if ($i=1){ 
                     echo "<div class='item active'><img src='images/art/$id/$archivo' style='max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px' /></div>";
                 } else {
                     echo "<div class='item'><img src='images/art/$id/$archivo' style='max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px' /></div>";
                 }
                 $i++;
             }
         }
     } ?>
     </div>

     <a class="left item-control" href="#imagenes" data-slide="prev">
         <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
     </a>
     <a class="right item-control" href="#imagenes" data-slide="next">
         <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: He editado mi repsuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de ver el error en el if

tiene que ser `if (1 === $i)` o `if (1 == $i)` también puedes poner antes la variable pero poniendo el número antes evitas asociación accidental

`===` = identico

`==` = igual

`=` = asociarle valor

Aquí tienes algo de información sobre las condiciones "Yoda"

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ese mismo era el problema, es que a veces por mas que uno mira no se da cuenta de los detalles. Saludos.

Comment: De nada, si no te importa marca mi respuesta como solución, saludos.